# Not able to create a simple DataBase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making my final year project about Islam. I want to use SQLite database in it. But I am not able to simply create database in it.I want to add daily namaz attendance in it.
and second one **how i set the type of a column to date** Help me.... Thanks in advance..!!!

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Shakeel Mughal on 5/29/2018.
 */

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String databasename="Test.db";
    public static final String Tbname = "student_table";
    public static final String Col_1 = "ID";
    public static final String Col_2 = "Name";
    public static final String Col_3 = "Class";
    public static final String Col_4 = "Marks";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databasename, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Tbname+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Class TEXT, Marks INTEGER)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Tbname);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

**My main activity for database
NamazCounterActivity,java**

```
package com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NamazCounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper mydb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_namaz_counter);


        mydb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        mydb.getWritableDatabase();

        //home button
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }


    }

    //function for going back to previous activity
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine e.g. using your code resulted in :-

```
Database Version = 1
Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
Table Name = student_table Created Using = CREATE TABLE student_table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Class TEXT, Marks INTEGER)
Table = student_table ColumnName = ID ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
Table = student_table ColumnName = Name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
Table = student_table ColumnName = Class ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
Table = student_table ColumnName = Marks ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
Table Name = sqlite_sequence Created Using = CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
```

So that answers ***"Not able to create a simple DataBase
"***

There is no specific Data Type for dates in SQLite. In fact in SQLite the type is not all that relevant as you can store any type of value in any type of column (except for an alias of the **rowid** column which can only be INTEGER).

What's is important is how you save the data. There are marked advantages in storing a date in a recognised format/type.

e.g. as per :-

> 2.2. Date and Time Datatype SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And
>   Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as
>   TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

## [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

In short the above link is a MUST READ and really the answer for your question ***"how i set the type of a column to date "***. It also expands upon the very brief overview given.

You may also find this link useful [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

### Demonstration

The following code is an example of the flexibilty of column types, how dates can be stored and some general ways of storing an accessing data. Using your database and table (see comments and notes):-

```
    DBHelper mydb; //<<<< Note the DatabaseHelper class has been renamed for my convenience
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = mydb.getWritableDatabase();

    sqldb.delete(DBHelper.Tbname,null,null); //<<<< delete all rows, if any

    //Prepare to insert a row
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBHelper.Col_2,"2018-01-01 10:30:00"); //<<<< recognised date format
    cv.put(DBHelper.Col_3,100.99D); //<<<< Double into a column defined as TEXT
    cv.put(DBHelper.Col_4, "Sorry you scored nothing"); //<<<< Text into an INTEGER
    sqldb.insert(
            DBHelper.Tbname,
            null,
            cv
    );
    cv.clear();
    // Prepare to insert a 2nd row
    cv.put(DBHelper.Col_2,"Fred");
    cv.put(DBHelper.Col_3,System.currentTimeMillis()); //<<<<< can be used stores long as INTEGER
    sqldb.insert(DBHelper.Tbname,null,cv);

    // get all the rows from the table
    Cursor csr = sqldb.query(DBHelper.Tbname,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DATA",
                "ROW " + csr.getPosition() +
                        " has a value of " +
                        String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_1))) +
                        " in the " + DBHelper.Col_1 +
                        " column, a value of " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_2)) +
                        " in the " +
                        DBHelper.Col_2 +
                        " column, a value of " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_3)) +
                        " in the " +
                        DBHelper.Col_3 +
                        " column, and a value of " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_4)) +
                        " in the " +
                        DBHelper.Col_4 +
                        " column."
        );
    }
    csr.close(); //<<<< Should always close a Cursor when done with it
```

The above results in the following being output to the log :-

```
ROW 0 has a value of 5 in the ID column, a value of 2018-01-01 10:30:00 in the Name column, a value of 100.99 in the Class column, and a value of Sorry you scored nothing in the Marks column.
    ROW 1 has a value of 6 in the ID column, a value of Fred in the Name column, a value of 1527600028305 in the Class column, and a value of null in the Marks column.
```

- the id's are higher than expected due to a few runs of the App.
- 1527600028305 is the timestamp when this was run.